# How do disable background downloads?

Tags: macos

App Store just ate all my mobile data trying to download Xcode. Is there a way to tell OS X that WiFi I'm currently using is expensive and it should not download its stuff without asking me first?

Comment: https://www.tripmode.ch might help.

Comment: This is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3):

Xcode will not download automatically until you actually press the download button in the App Store.

The only way I can think of minimising the chance of using the WiFi extensively is to disable the installing available updates in the background.

Go to App Store->Preferences->uncheck Download newly available updates in the background

[image: App Store preferences screenshot]

You could uncheck the automatic check for updates all together, but this increases the risk of not getting latest security updates - what is not really recommended.

All these modifications mean that you would need manually download updates.

Comment: It would be awesome if there was a tool that pauses these settings. For when you are on limited data wifi or cellular...

Comment: @pjctech I don't see a way for macOS to recognise limited data as it doesn't have the internal cellular module (where you insert the SIM card). Meaning if you connect for example your iPhone's wireless hotspot running on a limited data to macOS then macOS will recognise it as a WiFi network.

Comment: Is there a way to change those settings programmatically?

Comment: @alljamin Win10 has metered connections for this purpose.

Comment: @Bowen how is this relevant for Apple software/hardware forum? Are you suggesting spinning a VM just for this purpose?

Comment: @pjctech May be there is one, but I'm not aware of it.